# Prevent direct access to html file but allow through PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a section of my website I would like to protect. I have created a php script to authenticate passwords and once authenticated, I would like them to be directed to an html page.

```
www.mywebsite.com/protectedfolder/index.html
```

I don't want users to take the above url, paste it into their browsers and have access to the page however. Do I have to add something my .htaccess file?

Comment: You're asking how to prevent users from accessing a page if they're not logged in?

Comment: I have no login management implemented, it's just a password that, if right should direct them to the html page.

Comment: It's probably best to set a session id, and then to only allow people to access that page if they have a session set

Comment: Note @PaulG both of the answers below used together are a good idea for increased security

Answer (score 2):

add this in .htaccess file in parent folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^protectedfolder/index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
# OR THIS TO PROTECT ALL FOLDER
# RewriteRule ^protectedfolder / [NC,R,L]
```

or create .htaccess file in protected folder and write this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

when php script runs and it accesses files it does from current user (not through http). so when trying to read file from protected folder using php's file_get_contents(), readfile(), fopen() and etc. apache's rules does not prevent php to make IO operations with file system.

and if we want output files from protected folder to authenticated users we have to run something like:

```
if(hasAccess()) {
    print readfile('path/to/protectedfolder/file.html');
}
```

Comment: To the .htaccess file inside the protectedfolder?

Comment: Important to note that the second implementation would block any attempts to get at the server that isn't calling `loccalhost` in the browser, on the same machine this site is running.

Comment: Hence the second answer is really the best here. PHP files outside of the protected folder can still access the html files as the OP requested.

Comment: when php script runs and it accesses files it does from current user not through http. so when trying to read file from protected folder using php's file_get_contents() function or doing fopen() apache's rules does not prevent php to make io operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I still have no access. I have tried $url = '../protectedfolder/index.html'; header( "Location: $url" ); and I get a 403 (forbidden) error.

Comment: of course You'll get 403, You're forwarding user to folder with closed to access outside. try: print readfile($url);

Comment: Thanks, will this work if the html page required js files?

Comment: Yes, have to work, maybe happen some url problems, but it's quickly fixed by givin full route to js, css files from root

Comment: @num8er your answer would benefit from editing it to add your upvoted comments

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP and a form with password input that would provide a POST request to the server.

```
<form action="index2.php" method="POST">
    <input name="pass" type="password" />
</form>
```

Then in PHP

```
if (empty($_POST["pass"]) || $_POST["pass"] != "yourpasshere") {
    header("Location index1.html");
    die();
}
//your second page here
```

EDIT:
You could also do this with sessions, where a user logins at a certain location, you give them a session name like `$_SESSION["name"] = "admin";` and then check for that in a way similar to above with

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION["name"])) {
    header("Location index1.html");
    die();
}
//your second page here
```

Comment: your second answer is much better

Comment: @nomistic Thanks, I like that implementation much more as well, and would suggest that as the way the asker implements the solution. I answer askers' questions the way they asked them first before providing personal opinion.

Comment: you might want to demonstrate how to set the session with the login page, and then  show to have them locked out on the destination page.  (header redirects are good.  I also like to make sure nothing is viewable if the script breaks halfway through, e.g. an `exit()` )

Comment: @tucuxi the asker was not explicit in what "secure," "password," or "protect" mean to them. Does it mean only accessible via local machine? Then use the other answer. Does it mean login with an admin password? Then something similar to this implementation is right. Technically, yes, the page would be externally accessible, but would only divulge enough info to turn an unauthenticated user away. No other parts of the page would be visible after that first `if` statement if a user didn't use the right POST password or have the right SESSION.