# Folder access overriding url routing in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, directory

I am trying to write a PWA ready MVC framework in PHP. Controllers and Models are written in PHP, and the views are plain HTML assisted by AJAX.

So I started by building a URL routing class to manage requests. I also wrote a Session class, and it is working fine.

But my problem here is, I need some static HTML pages at the client side, for caching purposes. But I don’t want these files to be accessed without login. Let’s say I have a folder structure such as:

```
    / LIBS
        / route.php
    / Static
        / index.html
    index.php
```

When I enter a URL like: `mysite.com/foo/bar`, routing class does the job and returns an array:

```
array (
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 'bar',
)
```

That is good. But when I enter `mysite.com/static` it just goes into STATIC folder and brings index.html which is located inside that folder.

I want these files be accessed via php with Session control, after successful login. But I don’t want my visitors to access these files before logging in.

I tried to disable the access with htaccess, but this time I could not access them via PHP either.

**Here is my index php:**

```
<?php
include "/LIBS/route.php";
$route = new Route;
$route->init();
```

**Here is my Router**

```
<?php
class Route {
    // Prints the URL array
    public function init()
    {
        echo '<pre>' . var_export($this->_getUrl(), true) . '</pre>';
    }
    // gets the current URL and returns an array
    private function _getUrl()
    {
        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
    }
}
```

**And here is my htaccess file**

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc/

# DirectoryIndex none.none
# Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

There is a kind of relevant SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443118/prevent-direct-access-to-html-file-but-allow-through-php) which doesn't seem to be the answer to my question.

I digged everywhere but could not find an answer. What am I missing?

Thanks